# Set theory (Disjoint union)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n}$ be $n$ sets and let $A_{i}^{k}=A_{i}$ if $k=1$ and $A_{i}^{k}=A_{i}^{c}$ if $k=-1$

Consider $E_{k}=A_{1}^{k_{1}}\cap A_{2}^{k_{2}}\cap...\cap A_{n}^{k_{n}}$ and $k_{i}=\pm1$ where there are $2^n$ such $E_{k}$'s and here $k$ is like a vector with 0 and 1.

I need to verify that any $A_{i}$ can be expressed as $A_{i}=\cup\{{E_{k}}:k=(k_{1},k_{2},...,k_{i-1},1,k_{i+1},...,k_{n})\}$

If $x\in RHS$, then $x$ is in one of the $E_{k}$ with $k_{i}=1$ and $A_{1}^{k_{1}}\cap A_{2}^{k_{2}}\cap...\cap A_{i-1}^{k_{i-1}}\cap A_{i}\cap A_{i+1}^{k_{i+1}}\cap...\cap A_{n}^{k_{n}}$ is clearly a subset of $A_{i}$.
We then have $RHS\subseteq LHS$

How do I verify $LHS\subseteq RHS$? On a Venn diagram it is quite obvious that both sides are equal but how can I verify it algebraically?

Comment: Are the $A_{i}$'s disjoint? Suppose there are just $A_{1}$ and $A_(2)$ and neither is a subset of the other. Then both $A_{1} \cap A_{2}$ and $A_{1} \cap A_{2}^{c}$ are proper subsets of $A_{1}$.

Comment: The $A_{i}$'s need not be disjoint but the $E_{k}$'s are disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in A_i$.

For $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ let $k_j=1$ if $x\in A_j$ and let $k_j=-1$ if $x\in A_j^{\complement}$.

Then evidently $x\in A_1^{k_1}\cap\cdots\cap A^1\cap\cdots\cap A_n^{k_n}=E_{(k_1,\dots,1,\dots,k_n)}$.

So every element of $A_i$ will be an element of the union on RHS.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.